# Check if an element is present after state update - react testing library nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs, react-testing-library

I want to test one of my NextJS component which is a searchbar with a div that display only if the state "search" is not empty.

```
const SearchBar = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

    const handleSearch = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        startTransition(() => {
          setSearch(e.target.value);
        });
    };

    return (
    <>
        <input onChange={handleSearch} />
        {search.length > 0 && (
            <div>...</div> 
    </>);
}
```

I started to use react testing library today to test my project and my components. I had no problem until that question of testing if that div is displayed when the search state is not empty.
I saw it's possible to test with the "Enzym" library but is there a way to test it properly with react testing library ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The input `type=text` or with a missing or invalid `type`, with no `list` attribute has a `textbox` role. So you can use `screen.getByRole('textbox')` to get the input element, then use [`fireEvent.change(input, {target: {value: ''}})`](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/) to change the value of the input like an user. It will trigger the `onChange` event, the `search` state will be updated, and the component will re-render.

Then, use `queryByText('...')` find the `div` element and assert whether it is present in the document or not.

E.g.

`SearchBar.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export const SearchBar = () => {
  const [search, setSearch] = useState('');

  const handleSearch = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSearch(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input onChange={handleSearch} />
      {search.length > 0 && <div>...</div>}
    </>
  );
};
```

`SearchBar.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React from 'react';
import { SearchBar } from './SearchBar';

describe('72049901', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    render(<SearchBar />);
    expect(screen.queryByText('...')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole('textbox'), { target: { value: 'a' } });
    expect(screen.queryByText('...')).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole('textbox'), { target: { value: '' } });
    expect(screen.queryByText('...')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/72049901/SearchBar.test.tsx (10.798 s)
  72049901
    ✓ should pass (84 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 SearchBar.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.341 s
```